# Websphere liberty 19 configure jndi datasource

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I have deployed two ears and to one of them i do not have access.
There is a file 
application-web-bnd.xml where is reference to datasource

In my server.xml file i have defined datasource

```
 <application id="MyCustomApp.war" location="F:\programming\source\MyCustomApp\target\MyCustomApp" name="MyCustomApp" type="war">
    <application-bnd>
      <security-role name="admin">
        <special-subject type="ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS" />
      </security-role>
      <data-source binding-name="jdbc/Sample" name="java:comp/env/jdbc/db" />
    </application-bnd>
  </application>

  <dataSource id="Sample" jndiName="jdbc/Sample" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <jdbcDriver>
      <library name="JdbcJarFiles">
        <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}" includes="db2jcc4.jar, db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar, db2jcc_license_cu.jar, pdq.jar, pdqmgmt.jar" />
        <folder dir="${shared.resource.dir}" />
      </library>
    </jdbcDriver>
  </dataSource>
```

In code in ear where i do not have access there is initialContext
java:comp/env/jdbc/db.

Reference to data source exists but datasource does not exists.
I do not have access to web.xml for create reference .
I do not have ide how override it.

Could You help ?

My ear looks that:

```
 <module>
    <ejb>PRE-BF.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>PRE-WS.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/PRE-WS</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>PRE-RS.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/PRE-RS</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>PRE-PF.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/PRE-PF</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override bindings in server configuration as follows.  (This will require having your application defined in server configuration rather than dropins).

```
<application location="MyApp.war">
  <web-bnd moduleName="MyApp">
    <resource-ref name="jdbc/Sample" binding-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/db"/>
  </web-bnd>
</application>
```

Comment: The example had a mismatch between application-bnd and web-bnd because I was misreading application-web-bnd.xml as application bindings, vs web module bindings.  I updated it for web-bnd

Comment: Thank You. I did not know that we can do that. Where is that knowledge ?;) In home i have created two war apps to test but in company i have two ears . Inside ear i have 3 wars. Still i should use web-bnd tag ?

Comment: I assume that i should use tag enterpriseApplication in server.xml but i do not know how to configure wars in that ear to pass datasource reference.

Comment: I really i do not know how to override resources in ear -> wars and jar. I do not know how to match it. I tried allot of combinations. I have never seen in java:comp/env/jdbc/somekindofsource. Maybe i need to create some custom factory ? Does exist some example ?

Comment: For .ear files, it is fine to use either `<enterpriseApplication>` or `<application>`.  Given that you have multiple modules, you will need to ensure that a `<web-bnd>` entry with the corresponding `moduleName` is specified for each of the web modules where you want to override the resource reference.  And likewise with `ejb-jar-bnd` and corresponding `moduleName` for EJB modules.  It can be a bit tricky to get the syntax right.  I tried out an override of a resource reference in a web module in this manner and it worked fine for me once I got the module name correct.

Comment: Here is a link to knowledge center documentation listing the syntax for specifying `<web-bnd>` or `<ejb-jar-bnd>` and so forth under `<application>`.  You'll need to scroll or search for these sub-elements, because the list of config options available for application is quite lengthy,
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.liberty.autogen.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_config_application.html